# GLSL Vector multiplication returns error? Model is not rendered

Tags: opengl, glsl, multiplication

I've been trying to study opengl for a fun side project and ran into some issue while learning.

Below is a fragment shader:

```
#version 330 core
in vec3 Normal;
in vec3 Position;
in vec2 TexCoords;
out vec4 color;

uniform vec3 cameraPos;
uniform samplerCube skybox;

struct Material{
    sampler2D diffuse0;
    sampler2D specular0;
    sampler2D emitter0;
    sampler2D reflection0;
    float shininess;
};
uniform Material material;


void main(){

    vec3 I = normalize(Position - cameraPos);
    vec3 R = reflect(I, normalize(Normal));

    float intensity = 0;
    intensity += texture(material.reflection0, TexCoords).x;

    vec4 rfl = texture(skybox, R);

    //this line doesnt produce anything
    color = rfl * intensity;

}
```

When i used the code above, my model is completely gone from view.

But, if i debug it out separately such as changing the line

```
    color = rfl * intensity;
```

to

```
    color = rfl;
```

This actually renders and returns the following picture
[image: with colors]

And changing that line to

```
   color = vec4(intensity);
```

It renders and returns the following picture
[image: with colors]

I've tried changing

```
   color = rfl * some constant
   //or
   color = vec4(0.5) * intensity
```

And both rendered my model normally. I'm stumped as to why it doesnt render when i tried multiplying both rfl and intensity together. I think it might be because there are values that the multiplication to fail, but i have no idea what they might be.

Comment: Does `color = rfl * vec4(intensity)` work?

Comment: edit: I've misread your comment, and rfl * vec4(intensity) does not work

Comment: How about    color = vec4(rfl * intensity) and    color = vec4(vec3(rfl*intensity), 1.0) ?

Comment: As MrShoor answered below, it seems that i missed the texture uniform binding to the shader.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Then you change

```
color = rfl * intensity;
```

to

```
color = rfl;
```

GLSL compiler will drop

```
uniform Material material;
```

due optimization. Same happens with skybox when you change line to:

```
color = intensity;
```

Make sure that you binding of texture uniforms is correct.

Comment: Thank you! I seemed to have forgotten to bind the texture uniform to the shader.